# Different Variables/Functions for one twig.html

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, dashboard

Since 3 weeks i try to learn php with the symfony framework.
I want to build an application with which i can track my expanses.

I made good progress but since 2 days i have a little logic problem so maybe someone can help me here.

I want to make a dashboard.(the main side of the project) There the user can monitor the expenditures.
This works. Now i want also a form at the dashboard, so the user can add new expenditures. I already implement a form but with a extra route. So in my **ExpenditureController** i have the **functions dashboard** and the **function addExpenditure** which generate different twig.html templates.

So the user can monitor his expenditures with ...budgetapp/expenditure/dashboard
and he can add new Expenditure with ...budgetapp/expenditure/addexpenditure

**My Dashboard-Function**

```
    #[Route('/dashboard/', name: 'dashboard')]
public function dashboard(ExpenditureRepository $ar)
   {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $expenditures = $ar-> findexpendituresOfUser($user);

    return $this->render('expenditure/dashboard.html.twig', [
    'expenditures' => $expenditures,
       ]);
}
```

**The expenditure/dashboard.html.twig shows the Expentiures of the current user in a table**

**My addExpenditure-Function**
public function addExpenditure (ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request){

```
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $expenditure = new Expenditure();
    $form = $this->createForm(ExpenditureType::class, $Expenditure);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $em->persist($expenditure);
    $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('expenditure/addexpenditure.html.twig', [
        'addexpenditureForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

**The expenditure/addexpenditure.html.twig looks like this:**

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
{{form(eintragenForm)}}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

My problem /mistake in thinking:
How can i implement the form to the dashboard? So of course i can take the code from the addexpenditure function and put it 1:1 in the dashboard-funciton. but i dont think this is the right way? I also tried to including template fragments with the offical [Embedding Controllers Documentation of Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers), but this also dont work.
So someone can help me with a suggestion how you would handle this in your project?

Best regards
Markus

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible solutions: put both **view** and **add** logic inside one controller's action, or separate them. Since you probably have some validation, it's  reasonable to have both add and view code inside one action (otherwise, you'll have to pass errors via sessions, which is not very pretty). So basically, your dashboard/add action will look like this:

```
#[Route('/dashboard/', name: 'dashboard')]
public function dashboard(Request $request, ExpenditureRepository $ar, ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
{
    $expenditure = new Expenditure();
    $form = $this->createForm(ExpenditureType::class, $expenditure);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $doctrine->getManager();
            $em->persist($expenditure);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
        }
    }

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $expenditures = $ar-> findexpendituresOfUser($user);

    return $this->render(
        'expenditure/dashboard.html.twig',
        [
            'expenditures' => $expenditures,
            'addexpenditureForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

What's happening here:

- First you check if POST http method was used, if it was - it means
  that form has been submitted and you can handle it. *There is an alternative solution without checking request method, see comments for more.*
- If this is a GET request, just show ordinary dashboard
- If the form is submitted and it's valid - save data and redirect to
  the same page. Otherwise, you'll need to empty all submitted data
  from the form, etc. (it's not the right way to do it)
- If the form is invalid, do not redirect, just render the page
  normally, and all errors will be shown.

Finally, you of course have to render the form on your dashboard.html.twig like you did: `{{form(eintragenForm)}}`

Comment: Your opening statement about not using embedded controllers is not only inaccurate but somewhat misleading.  The debug toolbar does not use embedded controllers.  And there are a number of use cases where embedded controllers make sense.  Including re-using the same form/controller combo.  I'm not saying the rest of your answer is wrong.  I confess I got bored reading the original question and have no idea what is being asked.  Your proposed solution might be ideal.

Comment: I think checking if you have a POST request with `if ($request->isMethod('POST'))` to know if form is submitted  is redundant since you already check it with `$form->isSubmitted()`.

Comment: @Skunka yes, you are right. I just don't like calling handleRequest unless I'm sure it was a post request. Basically, you can call handleRequest all the time, and only check `isSubmitted()` instead of `isMethod('POST')`.

Comment: @Cerad okay, I agree with you, it's more like a personal taste. I personally don't like using this feature to avoid handling main/sub requests logic, etc. And also it's critical for highload systems, because it takes a little bit more time to process a sub-request. But in order to simplify answer, I removed that statement, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially Hast! I put my add and view logic in the same action of my Controller. This works fine. 

I have one last question, just to unterstand everything right.
Its "normal" to put different logics in one actions? And the other way (for special/other application areas) are embedded controllers? Because i thought that my contoller action dashboard is not well structured when i put add and view logic in it.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @LittleEast in your case It's okay to use the same controller, because you do not have a separate "add" page. It's also reasonable to move all "add" logic to a different private method of your controller though. Alternatively, you can create a separate "add" page with the form and all the processing to not mix it with the dashboard view page. As for embedded controllers: it makes sense to use it when the same form/view is used on several different pages of your app, like some global thing. For example form for changing website language, etc. But this is not your case.